# hide div if there is no paragraphs

Tags: php, jquery

So I have several divs that i assigned a class to.  Each div has a header.  The contents underneath each header are dynamically generated via php.  Certain times of the year these divs contain no information but the header still displays.  I want to hide the divs that do not have any paragraphs inside of them  I cannot quite get them to work and I have a feeling it has to do with the paragraphs being generated by php.

EXAMPLE:

```
<div class="technology_connected article_headers"> 
  <h3>TECHNOLOGY CONNECTED</h3> 
  <?php echo $tools->article_formatter($articles, 'Technology Connected'); ?>
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".article_headers").each(function() {
      if ($(this).find("p").length > 0) {
         $('.article_headers').show();
       }
    });

});
```

Comment: So how looks like the rendered HTML?

Comment: Shouldn't this be a server-side task?

Comment: All of the divs still show regardless if there are any paragraphs or not.

Comment: hmmm I figured I could hide/show still with Jquery.

Comment: Are the divs hidden by default?

Comment: @NickBalistreri You _could_ hide/show them with jQuery, but unless there's something else in the equation that we aren't seeing, you probably _should_ hide them with php.

Comment: @NickBalistreri I agree with _Jason P_ about hiding the `<div>`'s server side if you don't want them visible and that's the only function of the JavaScript on the front end. If you do want to hide them on the front end, though I've outlined a simple solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".article_headers").each(function() {
      if ($(this).find("p").length > 0) {
         $(this).show();
       }else{
         $(this).hide();
       }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8PpTN/)**

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @JasonP above, this really should be done server side. However, since you do want it done server side, you can simplify the process greatly. Generate the data server side as you're doing. Make sure all `<div>` tags are visible. Then in your JavaScript use the following selector:

```
// Shorthand for $(document).ready(function() { ... });
$(function () {
    $('.article-headers:not(:has(p))').hide();
});
```

The selector above targets all elements with the class `.article-headers` that do not contain a `<p>` tag and hides them.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/a6E4P/1/)** demoing the above as a toggle button to show or hide the no paragraph sections.